# SQL query involving regular expressions

Tags: sql

I have a database Recipe table which looks like that:

```
(irrelevant fields skipped)
ingredients VARCHAR(500)
ingNo INT
```

The example ingredient fields have the form:

```
'pepper :1 \n tomato :2 \n salt :half a spoon'

'egg :1 \n tomato :1 \n potato :5'

'rice :100 gram \n oil :1 spoon'
```

Now, I would like to form select statement which selects tuples according to given ingredients, for example if I choose 'tomato' and 'potato' it should return recipes with the most of those ingredients (so from the example above it should be tuple 2 and 1, exactly in that order). If there are more tuples with the same number of matches, the query should sort tuples according to number of matches divided by ingNo. How to to it in SQL?

Comment: While you might be able to do this, ultimately you are heading in the wrong direction here.  The real problem is that ingredients should be a separate table related to the Recipe table with a many-to-one relationship.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to redesign your database. Use two tables. One is the recipe. The second references the recipe and contains an ingredient and a measurement.

```
recipe
    - irrelevant fields
ingredient
    - recipeID
    - name
    - measurement
```

Comment: measurement should also be a separate table - think a numeric "quantity" field and a "UnitOfMeasureID" related to another UnitOfMeasure table with various values (each, teaspoons, ounces, cups, etc.)

Comment: Thank you, that was a truly bad design indeed.

Comment: @Eric, true, measurement is likely better off as a separate table

Answer (score 1):

You could use a UNION query:

```
select recipe from sometable where ingredients LIKE '%tomato%'
UNION
select recipe from sometable where ingredients LIKE '%potato%';
```

And then there are some full-text options that are unique to your database engine that you could also look into.

Comment: That's not a scalable solution. That will work for two ingredients, but you need to re-write the query for three ingredients, etc.